# Do operation and add it to new column depending on pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1                         COL2 COL3   COL4
SEQ_1:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_37   1    40     80000
SEQ_2:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_35   90   456    766
QTTSS:XGGGD(+)JJDDH_0        4    990    3556
QTTSS:XGGGD(-)JJDDH_099      6    7789   90000
HYYH:LHGGH(+)FTT_H           667  88990  150000
```

and I would like to add 2 new columns =  `COL2bis` `COL3bis`

when there is a `(+)` in `COL1` the  `COL2bis` `COL3bis` take the same values as  `COL2` `COL3` BUT

when there is a `(-)' in`COL1`:

```
COL2bis = COL4 - COL3
COL3bis = COL4 - COL2
```

here the output hsould be

```
COL1                         COL2 COL3   COL4    COL2bis  COL3bis
SEQ_1:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_37   1    40     80000   79960    79999
SEQ_2:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_35   90   456    766     310      676
QTTSS:XGGGD(+)JJDDH_0        4    990    3556    4        990
QTTSS:XGGGD(-)JJDDH_099      6    7789   90000   82211    89994
HYYH:LHGGH(+)FTT_H           667  88990  150000  667      88990
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [56]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [57]: df['COL2bis'] = np.where(df['COL1'].str.contains('-'), df['COL4'] - df['COL3'], df['COL2'])

In [59]: df['COL3bis'] = np.where(df['COL1'].str.contains('-'), df['COL4'] - df['COL2'], df['COL3'])                                                                                                        

In [60]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[60]: 
                         COL1  COL2   COL3    COL4  COL2bis  COL3bis
0  SEQ_1:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_37     1     40   80000    79960    79999
1  SEQ_2:HDHD_DIDH(-):DUUD_35    90    456     766      310      676
2       QTTSS:XGGGD(+)JJDDH_0     4    990    3556        4      990
3     QTTSS:XGGGD(-)JJDDH_099     6   7789   90000    82211    89994
4          HYYH:LHGGH(+)FTT_H   667  88990  150000      667    88990
```